# symfony no table to create after creating the entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I created my entities using

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

I want to create the tables on the database. When I run

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql
or
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

im not getting the queries that needs to be for creating the tables .

Comment: When you do schema update, you say you don't have the queries then you say you have AUTO_INCREMENT. can you clarify? (And also, please add spaces in your text next time to be able to be understood...)

Comment: There are two different problems above.

Answer (score 0):

for the first problem i removed the directory MyBundle > Resources > Config > doctrine, in which I had some files like Entity.orm.yml then i run

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql`

it works